# How to solve "Unable to resolve module..." error with react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to learn to use react native and am following along with this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkualZPRZCs). I have encountered an error stating the following, "Unable to resolve the module ... from ...: could not resolve ... as a file nor folder." I am fairly certain that the file path used is correct and I have followed the video very closely, and it appears to work in this video. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am unfamiliar with using components in react.

**index.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

import Component1 from './app/components/Component1/Component1';

export default class myapp extends Component {
  render() {
    return(

      <View>
        <Component1 />
      </View>

    );
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => myapp);
```

**component1.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

export default class Component1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return(

      <View>
        <Text>This is Component 1.</Text>
      </View>

    );
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Component1', () => Component1);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `component1.js` has `c` small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this path to your component

```
import Component1 from './app/components/Component1/component1';
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. I copied the code you provided directly in and did not solve the issue. Instead it is now returning the path as in the last statement of the error as, "Users/spencermiller/Desktop/Coding/Apps/myapp/components/Component1/App".

Comment: After looking it over again, I see that in order to make the code match I had to actually change the name of the component1.js file to Component1.js! Thanks for the help once again.

Comment: @Spencer M. Glad to help